# How to pull branch at specific tag in Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there a way to make the `deploy-prod` job in my GitLab pipeline pull the `main` branch at a particular version tag instead of always pulling the latest code? Here $VERSION_NUMBER is a variable available in the pipeline

```
deploy-prod:
  tags:
    - prod-runner
  image: docker.xxx/nodejs:14
  stage: deploy-prod
  environment: 
    name: prod
  script:
    - npm install        
    - npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $VERSION_NUMBER != ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `before_script` to fetch all tags and in script do a checkout to specific tag by passing `VERSION_NUMBER`.

```
before_script:
  - git fetch --tags

script:
  - git checkout tags/${VERSION_NUMBER}
  # Your commands here...
```